# AppCompat Material Style widget tint error

Tags: android, android-appcompat

Im using the appcompat_v7 library.

In the documentation say:

[...] AppCompat provides similar behaviour on earlier versions of Android for a subset of UI widgets:

Everything provided by AppCompat’s toolbar (action modes, etc)

- EditText
- Spinner
- CheckBox
- RadioButton
- Switch (use the new android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat)
- CheckedTextView
  You don’t need to do anything special to make these work, just use these controls in your layouts as usual and AppCompat will do the rest (with some caveats; see the FAQ below).

This is my code:

values/styles.xml

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/material_blue_grey_800</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/material_blue_grey_950</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/material_deep_teal_200</item>
</style>
```

layout/activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.lollipoptest.MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
    android:text="CheckBox" />

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="RadioButton" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/radioButton1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:ems="10" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

No changes in the default MainActivity.java

The actionbar show the new Material style. The edittext too.
But the checkbox and the radiobutton not.
What im doing wrong?

Photo:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1jx6rK5CDqTRnhYVDU3V21JRlk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Which SDK level is the screenshot? I used exact the samething and the `Checkbox` style has changed in Jellybean device.

Comment: 2.2, i tried in 2.3 also.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
 <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/chbDevuelto"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:button="@drawable/abc_btn_check_material"
        android:buttonTint="@color/colorAccent"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:focusable="false" />
```

this lines do the trick:

`android:button="@drawable/abc_btn_check_material"
 android:buttonTint="@color/colorAccent"`

works in all versions :3

Comment: Very strange but indeed that `android:button="@drawable/abc_btn_check_material"` line fixed the missing tinting with the `appcompat-v7:21.0.(2|3)`.

Comment: How to give buttonTint ?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it will work for these versions. It simulates the tint used in lollipop. In versions lower than 4.0 radio buttons and checkboxes are just images. This is difficult to tint. Appcompat tints what it can tint. Try version 4.0 (Ice Cream Sandwich), from that version it will probably work.

Take a look at this, it is an article written by Chris Banes about Appcompat v21. 
https://chris.banes.me/2014/10/17/appcompat-v21/

You could use 4.0 as minimum SDK version. You have approximately 85% of the devices with supporting from 4.0. It also saves you a lot of trouble. Here is a link for more information: https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html

Comment: You are right. I think it is 85% overall. And more than 95% within the active users.

Comment: @FedeAmura What you could do is create a custom Radio button and checkbox for those lower versions. Here is a link that will help you: http://icetea09.com/blog/2014/01/22/android-custom-radio-button-custom-checkbox/

Answer (score 1):

This was a bug in AppCompat r22, some widgets (such as `Button`, `Checkbox`, and `RadioButton`) were not using the material-like backgrounds in Android 2.2/2.3.

It's fixed in AppCompat r22.1.

In short, it's no longer necessary to manually set `abc_btn_check_material` and similar resources as the background drawable for these widgets; the library does it automatically.